# Accidentally associated .EXE with Virtual PC

Tags: windows

I was trying to open a Virtual PC file that was in .exe format, so I went and pressed Open With, and selected Virtual PC.  I pressed ok and then tried to open it, but it didnt work.  Unfortunately, I forgot to uncheck *"use this program for all files of the same type"*.

How do I undo the file association and get my PC working again?

Comment: The extraneous exclamation marks and saying please over and over really don't make people want to help you.  Plus some proper capitalization and overall structure would be very helpful in getting questions answered in the future.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open **Command Prompt** by typing `cmd` in **RUN dialog box**.
2. Now provide following command: `cd\windows`
3. It'll activate Windows folder. Now provide following command to open Registry Editor: `regedit`
4. Now goto following key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe`

   In right-side pane, **change** the value of **Default** key to `exefile`
5. Now goto: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command`
   In right-side pane, change value of **Default** key to: `"%1" %*`
6. That's it. Now exit Registry Editor and restart your Windows. Now you should be able to open EXE files without any problem.

[Source](http://www.askvg.com/solution-exe-files-always-open-with-notepad-or-other-applications/)

Comment: Would that be... cmd.exe, by any chance? May have luck with command.com, though even then I'm not entirely sure how to interact with the registry without using reg.exe. Perhaps you could roll up the changes into a .reg file, that should work?