# Accidentally associated .exe files with java.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, java, file-association

I have downloaded a [YawCam.exe](http://home.bitcom.se/yawcam_files/yawcam_install.exe) program in order to take pictures with my webcam.

After installation I clicked its icon to start then it opened 'Open With...' dialog to select which program to be used to run it.

I thought that it was a Java program, so it (maybe) want me to show java.exe path to work.

Then I associated YawCam.exe to work with java.exe. What I did not notice "Alway use the selected program to open this kind of file" was checked.

Suddenly the icons of all my program shortcuts and start menu items changed to java's cup icon.

I have read a question similar to mine at [Accidentally associated .EXE with Virtual PC](https://superuser.com/questions/159183/accidentally-associated-exe-with-virtual-pc)

It sounds a good choice. But if try to run cmd command via 'Run...' dialog, Windows tries to open cmd.exe with java.exe

I also have tried to turn back to a checkpoint with system restore. Again I have encountered the same problem with cmd.exe

I have a solution in my head that creating a new account and continuing my work. But I will do that if I feel helpless.

I have tried what suggested at [How to repair a broken .EXE file association](https://superuser.com/questions/362827/how-to-repair-a-broken-exe-file-association) but did not work. After restart, background programs (like dropbox) did not started either.

Comment: Had this problem not too long ago with YawCam. I believe copying both the `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` into YawCam's installation folder did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Easy Fix Registry File I made just now. Since its a .reg it won't open with the Java. Copy the below contents and paste it in notepad, save it as fix.reg and run it. I've

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile]
@="Application"
"EditFlags"=hex:38,07,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,35,00,36,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.exe]
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.FileDescription;System.ItemTypeText;System.FileVersion;System.Software.ProductName;System.Software.ProductVersion;System.Copyright;*System.Category;*System.Comment;System.Size;System.DateModified;System.Language;*System.Trademarks;*System.OriginalFileName"
"InfoTip"="prop:System.FileDescription;System.Company;System.FileVersion;System.DateCreated;System.Size"
"TileInfo"="prop:System.FileDescription;System.Company;System.FileVersion;System.DateCreated;System.Size"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithProgids]
"exefile"=hex(0):
```

This will reset all possible conflicting Registry Keys to Default!

Comment: I have not tried yours but this file at http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/123734d1312706455-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_exe.reg  worked for me.

Comment: @SharadGautam Don't nag people to upvote and mark your answer as correct. If they decide it is right then they will, if not then it's not your place to harangue them about it.. Ramhound has a valid concern in that linking to random .reg files is a security problem and having the contents easily visible is good as it allows much better review.

Comment: Got it @Mokubai